# Element 'block': This element is not expected : magento2

Tags: magento2

I have created one extension it is not working in my custom magento application(2.2.4) but it is working fine in default magento2.2.4.

I am getting error because of below code
defaul.xml code:

```
<head>        
<block class="HK\Hplus\Block\CheckIframe" name="hplus_checkiframe" template="HK_Hplus::checkiframe.phtml"/>
</head>
```

============

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'block': This element is not expected. Expected is one of (
>   title, css, link, meta, script, remove, attribute ). Line: 715

When i run my page it is throwing above error
I have disabled all third party extension still getting this issue.
Same extension working fine in native magento.

Comment: You cannot add block to your head block on this way.

Comment: @SukumarGorai  it is working fine in default magento 2.2.4 so i don't think that is the reason.

Comment: In default magento did you use the same code on default.xml?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add block to your head block in this way. If you want to add then you can use the below code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="HK\Hplus\Block\CheckIframe" name="hplus_checkiframe" template="HK_Hplus::checkiframe.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```